# Error installing Java ME SDK 3.3 (preview) in NetBeans

Tags: java, netbeans

I've installed NetBeans 7.3 (with Java SE) and Java ME SDK 3.3 in Windows 8 Pro 64 bits.

I've downloaded the NetBeans plugin for Java ME SDK 3.3 and when I try to install it I get the following errors

[image: NetBeans Error]

I've never used Java before so any clue is welcome

Answer (score 0):

Try to open Tools >> Plugin

Open `Available Plugins` tab and install `Mobility` plugin

See if it solves the problem :)

Comment: The problem I've is that I need to install it in a PC that hasn't access to the internet. Is there a way to download it outside the NetBeans IDE?